# How to customize buttons using Child rows with DataTables

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

I used Child rows with DataTables. I want to customize the buttons (`open_details`and `close_details`). I want to use other images.
I am following [this](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/child-rows/whole-row-control.html) example.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to pay to change styling... and $119 *is* cheap for the product and support service they offer. I GLADLY paid.

Simply add these css overrides:

```css
/* when closed */
table.dataTable.dtr-inline.collapsed>tbody>tr[role="row"]>td:first-child:before, table.dataTable.dtr-inline.collapsed>tbody>tr[role="row"]>th:first-child:before{
    background-image: url('/your-closed-image.png');
    background-color: purple;
}

/* when open */
table.dataTable.dtr-inline.collapsed>tbody>tr.parent>td:first-child:before, table.dataTable.dtr-inline.collapsed>tbody>tr.parent>th:first-child:before{
    background-image: url('/your-open-image.png');
    background-color: black;
}
```

Should get you started in the right direction. Works best with transparent png images.

Comment: thank you, but how will I distinguish between the image open and close. I want to use two different images.

Comment: I added the css for both open/closed states above. You can see this yourself if you use Chrome browser Dev Tools in the Inspector tool.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to make changes to the styling you need to pay, and this is not cheap. It starts at €109 ($119 USD), on this page you can see all packages:
https://editor.datatables.net/purchase/index?currency=eur

And on this page you can see what you gain from paying for it:
https://editor.datatables.net